# Our users get a trojan horse alert on our site, but we don't. What do we do?

Tags: web-application, malware

A user of our website got a trojan horse alert when she tried to get to our website. But myself and some other friends got no alert whatsoever and can go on the website and download files without problems. I scanned my computer and found no traces of malware downloaded from visiting our own website. She seems to be the only one with this problem.

1. What could be the cause of this?
2. What should we do to ensure our website doesn't have malware, as owners of the site?
3. What can our user do (provided the problem is located on her end)?

Comment: I am sorry, not opening random sites. are you sure it is related?

Comment: You can scan your site via a tool like VirusTotal. For example here is the scan of your home page: https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/4fcfa02b18bfe24fe2330ea539974523b450e83529c345a3c4a86e377ce8987b/analysis/1453383388/. You may need to scan the different sections by hand.

Comment: I made significant edits to make the question stick to the editorial format of StackExchange. Please take a second to check if anything significant was lost in translation.

Comment: Happened to me. Nothing in Chrome, but something else in IE. -> Some exploit kits will do feature detection and only activate if a certain useragent string is sent. Thus if you surf to the site with an old and broken IE6, you will get a matching exploit delivered. And if you surf to the site with a fully patched Chrome, you will see nothing. -> Try with a different browser in a VM. Or try one of the many useragent switchers. (Or something like this: `wget --quiet -e robots=off --user-agent='Windows; rv:11.0' example.com` both with and without "--user-agent" and diff the files.)

Comment: Also: run URL through [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) and [URLVoid](http://www.urlvoid.com/).

Comment: To add to [Priyank Guta's](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/80108/priyank-gupta) answer, if your site has advertising it is possible that the provider you get your advertisements from is the actual source. Wouldn't be the first time.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

If she's the only one user getting this sort of alert, chances are that her machine is infected. If many users report this issue, it's time to get your website checked.

Also, if she's getting the alert from her legitimate anti-virus product, it could be the case of false-positive. A simple email to the anti-virus vendor would solve your problem.

As AstroDan suggested in comments, it would be better if you check your website using VirusTotal. You should particularly check the URL that the user is reporting.

If you find nothing wrong with your website, ask the user to:
1) Update their OS
2) Update the browsers
3) Use a legitimate anti-virus/anti-malware product, update it, and scan their machine(s).

Answer (score 1):

Some website virus infections are only active when the user reaches the website from a search-engine. This is done by checking the referer.
The idea is that normal users never type url's directly, only the owner of the website does that. And the virus does not want to alert the owner.

So for my suggestion: do a google search for you website and access it that way.